# Elmah log error page customization

Tags: c#, logging, elmah

I would like to use Elmah for logging of the operations in application and **not just for errors** *(I know it, literally means error logging module)*.

So, I would like to customize the default error view screen (../elmah.axd):

I have wishes like below:

1. **Change the Column Name "Error" for "Message"**
2. **Use html tags in the error message.**

For logging a custom information, I'm using a method like:

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Elmah.ApplicationException(message));
```

But it does show the message in a span tag and if I use any `<a href="">` or `<br />` or even `&lt;` the result is as written and not seen as html attribute.

---

*The default page is below for visual understanding:*

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elmah is a single dll, so you have to download the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/checkout), change rendering in ErroLogPage, ErrorDetailPage, rebuild, and deploy the modified assembly.

Or write a new custom display page that uses elmah errors directly stored in db/disk/etc.